# new to this - vibrate on tap (and open link)

Tags: html, hammer.js, vibration

Im working on a simple project and i am new to this(as the title says).
So what i want to happend is: When you tap a link(ommig) i want the unit to vibrate a bit. 
I tried to use Hammer.js lib but failed, I dont really mind using the html5 way, so im not all locked in to just be using hammer.js. 
So when I click the #ommig ID/class i want the unit to vibrate.
Please help a newbie in distress (and thanks for all the answers)

HTML (i deleted all my bad js code):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Start</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icon.jpg">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="hammer.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>


<body>

<a href="index.html">  <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="image">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="img/logo2.png" alt="image">
            <div class="carousel-caption">

            </div>
          </div>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</a>

<a href="ommig.html"> <div id="ommig"> <p>Om mig </p>
</div> </a>




<a href="cv.html"> <div id="cv">  <p> CV </p>
</div> </a>

<a href="portfolio.html"><div id="portfolio" >
  <p> Portfolio </p>
</div></a>
<a href="kontakt.html"><div id="Kontakt" >
<div id="kontakt" >
  <p> Kontakt </p>
</div></a>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your code instead of the link. Also, are you seeing a particular error?

Comment: No, i just dont understand how to do it. I found some examples but did not really understand(and copy paste didnt work out )

Answer (score 0):

There is a new HTML Vibrate API, but it is not very widely supported.

```
//Check if Vibrator is available, use custom browser prefix if needed
navigator.vibrate = navigator.vibrate ||
              navigator.webkitVibrate ||
              navigator.mozVibrate || 
              navigator.msVibrate;

if (navigator.vibrate) {
  console.log('vibration supported');
  navigator.vibrate(500);
} else {
  console.log('vibration not supported');
}
```

Read more here: http://shapeshed.com/html5-vibrate-api/